# How do you request device connection string in azure using python and iotHub library?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-iot-hub

I am wondering how can you get device connection string from IotHub using python in azure? any ideas? the device object produced by IoTHubRegisterManager.Create_device_with_sas(...) doesn't seem to contain the property connection string.

Comment: There are different ways to get the connectionString from AzureIotHub. There doesn't seems to be a direct way to get the connection string: [look at this](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python/blob/30282940e389e3dc1ad9a5c7149e0fcd86edf730/azure-iot-hub/azure/iot/hub/connection_string.py): and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-iot-hub/azure.iot.hub.connection_string.connectionstring?view=azure-python) see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a device connection string from the device registry. However, it is not recommended that you do that on a device. The reason being is that you will need the IoT hub connection string to authenticate with your hub so that you can read the device registry. If your device is doing that and it is compromised then the perpetrator now has your IoT hub connection string and could cause all kinds of mayhem. You should specifically provide each device instance with its connection string. 
Alternatively, you could research the Azure DPS service which will provide you with device authentication details in a secure manner.